# Unable to push or pull changes in amplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I need some help.

I tried to set a default value with `=`  in aws graphql API with AWS Amplify
like

```
type User
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: private, operations: [read]}]) {
  id: ID!
  isFavorite: Boolean
  logo: String
  status: String = "active" # the issue line
}
```

then I pushed the code but in the end I got an error:
`Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "="`

I then deleted this line but when I push or pull with `amplify push/pull` I get this error

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can define a default value for a string.

```
type Todo @model {
  content: String @default(value: "My new Todo")
}
```

AWS Documentation Reference: [Assign default values for fields](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#assign-default-values-for-fields)